# Performance issue: Spark-sql spent 0.5s process an empty kafka stream

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I'm following the Spark KafkaWordCount.scala example to process a Kafka stream.
To get a easy way to write the calc logic, I'm also using Spark-SQL.

The issue is I found each SQL query **spent 300 - 400 ms even for an empty stream!**
When I have a 2 seconds time window, this cost is too much.
The same logic wrote by Scala code only spent **10 - 12 ms**.

The Spark-SQL version:

```
def processBySQL(persons: RDD[Person], sqc: SQLContext) = {
  val ts = System.currentTimeMillis
  import sqc.implicits._
  val df = persons.toDF()
  df.registerTempTable("tb_person")
  sqc.cacheTable("tb_person")

  sqc.sql("SELECT count(1), age FROM tb_person GROUP BY age").collect().foreach(println)    

  sqc.uncacheTable("tb_person")
  println("[SQL]: " + (System.currentTimeMillis - ts) + " ms") //300 - 400ms
}
```

The Scala version:

```
  def processByCode(persons: RDD[Person]) = {
    val ts = System.currentTimeMillis

    persons.groupBy(_.age)
      .map(group => {
          val (age, items) = group         
          val size = items.size
          (items.last.name, items.size)
      }).collect().foreach(println)

    println("[CODE]: " + (System.currentTimeMillis - ts) + " ms") // 10 - 12ms
  }
```

Full test code here: https://gist.github.com/nonlyli/e247a576b275cd7b3d88

Any idea for this issue?

**Update 2015.09.21**: Upgrade to spark 1.5.0, test results no big difference.

Comment: interesting results, on my CPU the faster version still gets 50-120ms while the slower one is indeed around 300-400. Not sure it's a an issue per se as creating an SQL query and executing it will always be slower than just performing operations on the RDD itself. The SQL doesn't know the table is empty so you will suffer from all the initial overhead anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The sql and non-sql are not doing the same thing.  For instance, in the SQL version, you're calling cacheTable